# Looking to output timestamp to component for React Button onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I'm still learning the world of Javascript and React - please excuse my lack of knowledge :)

I'm trying to basically filter the number of clicks per day, i.e. using timestamp. My thought process for the initial stages is as so:

- in `onClick` function, set `time` to `moment().toDate()`
- output `this.state.time` to a React component in a separate stats.js file

`console.log(moment().toDate())` does output the timestamp when the button is pressed, which is good, but I can't get it to render.

Any ideas?

My App.js file so far:

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Header from '../components/Header.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { spring } from 'popmotion';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
const moment = require('moment');
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      response: undefined
    };
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      count: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) || 0
    });
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    this.setState({
      count: count
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(textValue => this.setState({ response: textValue }))
    .then(time => this.setState({ time: moment().toDate() }))
    .then(console.log(moment().toDate()));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <main>
            <Header />
              <div style={{paddingTop: "150px"}}>
                <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                  <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <h1 style={{ fontFamily:"Arial", fontSize:"50px" }}>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <form className="question-input" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <TextField
                        id="inputquestion"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        placeholder="Ask your question..."
                        margin="normal"
                        style={{ width:"200px", paddingRight:"10px" }}
                      />
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        type="submit"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={ this.incrementCounter.bind(this) }
                        id="submitquestion"
                        style={{ width: "100px", fontSize:17 }}>Shake Me!
                      </Button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <p>Magic 8 Ball says...</p>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <p>{this.state.response}</p>
                  </div>
                </Typography>
              </div>
        </main>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

My stats.js file (where I want to output the stats eventually):

```
import Header from '../components/Header.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Component } from "react";
const moment = require('moment');
import { Chart } from "react-charts";
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

class StatsPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      time: undefined
    };
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      count: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) || 0
    });
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    this.setState({
      count: count
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header />
          <h1>Game Statistics</h1>
            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <p>Total questions: {this.state.count}</p>
                </div>
                <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <p>Last question timestamp: {this.state.time}</p>
                </div>
              </Typography>
              <style jsx>{`
                h1 {
                  font-family:"Arial";
                  font-size:50px;
                }`}
              </style>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default StatsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting state in the app, but then you never use it. You're using state in StatsPage, but you never set it. Each component has its own state, so pick just one component that you want to be responsible for this, and handle it there. If you're unsure what component to do it in, find the highest component in the component tree that needs to interact with the time (either setting it or using it), and put the state there. It can then pass it down as a prop to any children that care about it.

Comment: Okay thanks - I've changed state in each component so the relevant states are only present.
Do you have any ideas on how I can get the `state.time` to show in statistics.js ?

Comment: If the time is a state of a parent component, then you can have that parent component pass the time down as a prop to StatsPage. StatsPage will then use `this.props.time`. If you can show us where you're rendering a StatsPage perhaps i can be more specific.